# XCode 11.6: Inconsistency due to missing image

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11, xcode-storyboard

I have a weird "bug" since yesterday. When I open my Xcode project and go to the storyboard, A warning message is displayed:
[image]

The image "icon_circle_green" exists well in my xcassets and the target is checked.
[image]

On top of that, in my storyboard I can see the image and set it as my button background (and then it is well displayed in the storyboard)
[image]

But when I run my App, the image is not displayed on my device. For information, I have another similar image "icon_circle_red" which is well displayed (I added "icon_circle_green" as new image set after "icon_cirlce_red")
I found some topics about this issue but none of the tricks works on my side (clean / rebuild / close / re-open XCode / disable source control / display source of storyboard to search for inconsistencies)

If someone can help :/

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the root cause of my issue. If you look at my last screenshot, I have a UIButton with a background (from custom image in my xcassets) and an image (from the system library).
-> it seems that it doesn't work with XCode. To fix it I just create my own "pencil" image that I put in xcassets and it works fine now.